# Best approach to follow when source is same and destinations are different in biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2013

I am in a situation where I need to develop the integration mechanism using biztalk server between different systems.

One of the scenario is as follows:

There is a source system (lets say S1) which generates some files in a folder and I used to pick these files,apply some logic and send to the destination systems. There are three different destination systems (D1,D2,D3) which needs to process the same files generated by source system S1. There is some defined frequency for all the three destination systems , to process the input files (generated by S1). So what should be the best approach in this scenario.

I have some in mind which are as follows , Please suggest me the best one.

-> Make three different orchestrations for the three different destinations.

-> Make one orchestration and manage the logic in that only.

-> Implement ESB. Is ESB worth of use in this scenario ?

Please suggest.

Comment: "There is some defined frequency for all the three destination systems" - Do you mean the targets can only accept data at specific times?  Usually, this is all driven by the source, meaning when it produces data, all 3 downstream system get it then.

Comment: If as @Johns-305 asks, some of the target systems only accept messages during a certain time one option is to `Enable service window` on the Transport Advanced Option in Send Port Properties pointing to that system.

Comment: Actually source will keep on producing the data but targets will accept the data at some defined frequency (let suppose after a time interval of 2 hours , 4 hours and 5 hours). The target system will accept the latest data.

Comment: So do you have to accumulate all the data from the source into a single message to send to the target system?  If so you will have to look at the Biztalk Sequential Convoy Pattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561843.aspx.  But watch out for Zombies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203853.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What logic are you actually thinking about?

In the most simple scenario you would only have 1 receive port and location and 3 send ports.
The send ports would subscribe (via the send port Filter) to the messages they need.

In order to do that, you would need to promote the necessary properties in your receive location (or orchestration, but that has a performance cost). It all depends on your logic, but probably you would be able to put most (if not all) logic in a BizTalk mapping.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the logic you need to apply on files for different destination, the question you will ask yourself are:
- Do you really need orchestration to apply the logic, can this be done using Inbound/outbound maps only or in pipeline. 
- Is logic significantly different for each destination? If not a common processing of message should be done.
- Do you need to do a extensible design i.e. Is there a need where you may need to add more destinations in future?

Based on your question details, it very difficult to come up with exact approach. As good as you can design the application which is easily maintainable and extendable, you should be fine with any approach. 
You should definitely look at ESB implementation for dynamic routing to different destinations.